# Android: Can't update UI after modifying database

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, realm, updating

my project involves the following:

1) An `EditText` view (`inputText`) in which the user is supposed to type a name

2) A `Button` that, when pressed, creates a Person object whose name is in `inputText` and saves that object to the realm database. Then it refreshes the `textLog` to include the new Person's name.

3) A 'TextView' (`textLog`) that shows a list of all the names of the Person objects in the realm database.

My problem is that clicking on the button refreshes the text log before it saves the person object to the database. This means the new person's name doesn't show up until I click the button again to create a newer Person object. I want the UI to refresh *after* the object is saved to the database, so it is always up to date. The following code is from my `MainActivity` class. Earlier I had done `Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`.

```
// called when button is clicked
private void submit(View view)
{
    final String input = inputText.getText()
                                  .toString()
                                  .trim();
    // asynchronous transaction
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(realm -> {
        realm.copyToRealm(new Person(input));
        handler.post(this::refresh);
    });
}

private void refresh()
{
    textLog.setText(realm.where(Person.class)
                         .findAll()
                         .stream()
                         .map(Person::getName)
                         .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess()` and `Realm.Transaction.OnError()` callbacks to your async transaction.  When those methods are called, you know the transaction is complete and you can refresh your UI.

Comment: Yes, that would fix his race condition, this is more specific than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). You do realm.executeTransactionAsync and then immediately do handler.post(this::refresh); - there's no guarantee that they'll execute in the order you want them to.